# C: How to put an arbitrary array in available memory? (basic)

Tags: c, arrays, memory

So, I'm trying to make a trivial program to reverse strings. I am *very* wet behind the ears when it comes to C, especially in understanding memory. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverser(char to_bb[]){
    int counter = strlen(to_bb);      /* size of entry */
    char reversed[counter];         /* creating blank array of same size */
    int counter2 = 0;
    for(counter - 1; counter >= 0; counter--){     /* loop to swap chars */
            reversed[counter2] = to_bb[counter];
            counter2++;
    }
    printf("The reversed: %s\n", reversed);
}

int main(){
    char to_be_reversed[20];
    puts("Enter the string to be reversed: ");
    scanf("%19s", to_be_reversed);
    reverser(to_be_reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I keep getting a bus error. I used `sizeof(to_bb)` and learned that it was 4 bits, indicating `to_bb[]` is merely a pointer within my void function. I have tried many ways to extract the string so I can manipulate it (i.e. call its elements), but I have not found success. I tried `strcpy()` and more long-winded declarations using `*`.

Thanks for any advice. Memory is proving challenging to understand!

Comment: You do not account for the terminator `\0` at the end and `for(counter - 1;` does nothing.

Comment: At least as stated, this code won't compile: "\\" is not a C-style comment. Could you please fix the code?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I have no comments in my personal code so I added them for this purpose only.

Comment: @Joe Okay, but even if the array is bigger, I will still encounter the initial problem. Will the null char be the first char in my reversed array? Is that a problem besides being sloppy?

Comment: @d0rmLife yes, the string will only output up to the '\0' (if it's the first character. did not study your code to know if that is what will happen)

Comment: @d0rmLife It is not just about making the array larger, you actually need to put the null terminator at the end to prevent `printf` from reading beyond the strings length.

Comment: @d0rmLife - `strlen` doesn't account for the terminating `'\0'`, so once you get your characters in reversed order, you also need to NUL-terminate the new string with `reversed[counter2] = '\0';`.

Comment: @Joe @David a theory question... so, why do I get a bus error when I do this: `printf("%s\n", to_bb[some_valid_number]);` BUT I am able to call the elements to swap them into `reversed[]`???

Comment: If `some_valid_number` is between `0` and `strlen(to_bb)` inclusive then it will print the characters starting at `some_valid_number` to the end.

Comment: @Joe But... it doesn't! That was part of my experimenting to try and understand my errors. Incorporating the given advice has given me a working program, but I tried the above `printf();` command just to see, and it still reports a bus error. Perhaps this is better served as a separate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for`, change `counter - 1` to `counter = counter-1` or, equivalently, `--counter`.

Add one more character to the size of `reversed` and set it to `'\0'`, so that it is null terminated. Alternatively, you can restrict the number of characters printed by using:

```
printf("The reversed: %.*s\n", counter2, reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You start with putting the `\0` character in your array, creating an empty string.

Quick fix, change

```
for(counter - 1; counter >= 0; counter--){
```

into

```
for(--counter; counter >= 0; counter--){
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to compile with warnings:

```
gcc -Wall yourfile.c

In function 'reverser':
11: 5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

The first part of a `for` statement is assignment: `counter - 1` does no assignment. Thus it does nothing and hence you get a warning telling you that you're not doing anything useful.

Another really useful operator you might want to learn about is the `,` opperator. It allows you to accomplish looping like this with less lines in the body of your loop.

```
for(counter -= 1; counter >= 0; counter--, counter2++)     /* loop to swap chars */
```

Finally you're not accounting for the `NULL` terminator. The function [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) gives you the number of characters in the string *not including* the `NULL` terminator.

So you should account for that yourself then after the loop append it, something like:

```
char reversed[counter+1];
int counter2 = 0;
for(counter - 1; counter >= 0; counter--, counter2++)     /* loop to swap chars */
        reversed[counter2] = to_bb[counter];
reversed[counter2] = '\0';
printf("The reversed: %s\n", reversed);
```

Comment: Very interesting about `-Wall`... gcc certainly has a lot of tools to learn about. Thanks for all the insights! Very helpful.